API platform - post/put request return body is null
When I make a POST/PUT request to create a new entity I get a null as body in return and I can't figure out why. The response code is a 201 created or 200 ok.
What I tried to rule out:

It's on all entities, so not a entity specific configuration
I have deleted all my custom event listeners to make sure it's not one of those
It's on both PUT and POST requests
The profiler gives no errors / deprecations whatsover
The accept header is application/json
The content-type is also application/json
When I do a GET request it gives me the correct response
The formats in api_platform.yaml is:
formats:
    json: [ 'application/json' ]
    jsonld: [ 'application/ld+json' ]



The versions I use:

API platform 3.3.14
Symfony 7



Why did you decide that the answer must be something in the body?

@mrmcwolf I have not decided yet, but the fact that it stores the data correctly in the database it is not something in de deserialization process. When I look at the profiler it also don't give anything in the "serialize" as if it gets stuck after the storing process. But my ideas are running out on what to debug next for finding the answer

You need to show the server part that handles the request. But once you get a valid response, it means there are no issues causing the crash. It is quite normal behavior to return only the status (although 201 is fine to at least return the id of the newly created record. But it can also return it as a header)

@mrmcwolf I don't know what to show than. The app uses the default API platform structure and I don't have custom configuration about the handling for the serialisation. The defaulft for API platform should be that it returns the entity when stored.
When I look into the generated api docs / open api specs, it also says it should return the entity. What indicates that my group normalization also is configured correctly (+ the fact that it happens on all my entities)

"The accept header is application/json" - Accept is used to indicate what type of response the client is willing to accept. But to indicate what type of content you are sending in the first place, there should be a Content-Type request header. From your current info, we can't tell if you are sending one.
